# Dragging a polygon in shapely

Tags: shapely

If I have a polygon and I translate it in a direction n to a new location, how can I create a new polygon formed by the act of translation?

To take a simple example consider the rectangle below  with vertices a,b,c,d, being dragged in the x-direction to create a1,b1,c1,d1.

```
d    c                            d1   c1  
o----o       ----> drag           o----o
|    !                            |    | 
|    !                            |    |
o----o                            o----o
a    b                            a1   b1
```

The output I want is a,b1,c1,d

```
d                                       c1 
o--------------------------------------o
|                                      |   
|                                      |
o--------------------------------------o
a                                      b1
```

Does shapely provide a way to do this? To be more precise, I am interested in the polygon defined by the set of points which are inside the polygon as it is dragged to the final position.

##### Edit: Seem to have made progress. See code below

Probably not very efficient, but seems to work

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import Polygon,Point
from descartes.patch import PolygonPatch

import numpy as np

GREEN = '#339933'
RED = '#ff3333'
BLACK = '#000000'


def drag_polygon(polygon,drag_vector):
    '''
    drags 'polygon' according to magnitude and direction in drag_vector
    
    polygon -> polygon to be dragged
    drag_vector -> vector to drag polygon
    every point x in the polygon moves to x+drag_vector
    
    returns a new polygon containing a set of points inside the polygon
    as it is dragged continuously along drag_vector
    
    implementation: 
        1) translate every edge of 'polygon' by 'drag_vector'
        2) for each pair of edge and translated edge
           create a polygon
        3) take the union of all polygons created in step 2
        4) take the union of the result of step 3 and 'polygon'
        5) return the union created in step 4   
    
    USE AT YOUR OWN RISK
    
    '''
    
    # create coordinates of final position of polygon
    # by adding drag_vector to every point
    
    drag_vector = np.asarray(drag_vector).reshape(1,2)
    exterior_coords=np.asarray(polygon.exterior.coords)
    
    # broadcasting magic
    shifted_exterior_coords=exterior_coords + drag_vector 
    
    npoints = len(exterior_coords)
    polylist = []
     
    # create polygons from each original edge
    # and its translated final position
    
    # loop over each edge in 'polygon'
    for ipoint in range(npoints-1):
        # points of the initial polygon
        p1       = exterior_coords[ipoint]
        p2       = exterior_coords[ipoint+1]
        # their final locations
        p1_shift = shifted_exterior_coords[ipoint]
        p2_shift = shifted_exterior_coords[ipoint+1]
        
        # at this point we know initial and final coords of current edge
        # use this information to create polygon by 
        # specifying vertices in the correct order
        # save it in polylist
        polylist.append(Polygon([p1,p2,p2_shift,p1_shift]))

    # initiaize union of all polygons
    union_poly = polygon
    
    # take the union with all polygons in polylist
    for pp in polylist:
        union_poly = union_poly.union(pp)
    
    return union_poly

# points defining polygon to be dragged
poly_points  = np.asarray([(0.0,0.0),(3.0,3.0),(0.0,5.0),(-5,5),(1,3)])
# specifies amount and magnitude of drag
drag_vector  = np.asarray((2.0,2.0))


fig,axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1,ncols=2)

poly_initial = Polygon(poly_points)
patch1 = PolygonPatch(poly_initial, facecolor=RED, edgecolor=BLACK, alpha=0.5, zorder=2)
axes[0].add_patch(patch1)

# shifted points
shifted_points = poly_points + drag_vector.reshape(1,2)
poly_shift     = Polygon(shifted_points)
patch2         = PolygonPatch(poly_shift, facecolor=RED, edgecolor=BLACK, alpha=0.5, zorder=2)
axes[0].add_patch(patch2) 

# centroid 
xcen = poly_initial.centroid.x
ycen = poly_initial.centroid.y

axes[0].arrow(xcen,ycen,drag_vector[0],drag_vector[1],width=0.1)

poly_dragged = drag_polygon(polygon=poly_initial,
                            drag_vector=drag_vector
                            )

# plot poly_dragged and initial and shifted polygon borders
patch3 = PolygonPatch(poly_dragged, facecolor=GREEN, edgecolor=BLACK, alpha=0.5, zorder=2)
_xx,_yy = zip(*list(poly_initial.exterior.coords))
axes[1].plot(_xx,_yy,color='black')
_xx,_yy = zip(*list(poly_shift.exterior.coords))
axes[1].plot(_xx,_yy,color='black')


axes[1].add_patch(patch3)

# get limits of axes so that all polygons can be seen
xmin = np.inf
xmax = -np.inf
ymin = np.inf
ymax = -np.inf
polygonlist = [poly_initial,poly_shift]

for pp in polygonlist:
    _xmin,_ymin,_xmax,_ymax = pp.bounds
    
    xmin = np.minimum(xmin,_xmin)
    ymin = np.minimum(ymin,_ymin)
    xmax = np.maximum(xmax,_xmax)
    ymax = np.maximum(ymax,_ymax)

for ax in axes:
    ax.set_xlim([xmin-1.0,xmax+1.0])
    ax.set_ylim([ymin-1.0,ymax+1.0])
    ax.set_aspect('equal') 

axes[0].set_title('initial and final polygons')
axes[1].set_title('dragged polygon (green)')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Strictly axis aligned movement on the x axis or ...?

Comment: @bugmenot123 No not strictly axis aligned. Movement along any vector in the plane.

Answer (score 3):

Below should work for most polygons (without holes):

1. Find the angle of your drag vector with x-axis (drag angle)
2. Rotate your polygon by negative of angle in #1 (affine.rotate). This will align your translation to x-axis
3. Find the bounds of aligned polygon: maxX, minX, maxY, minY
4. Break the polygon at Ymax and Ymin points into two LineStrings (L1, L2)
5. Find the LineString which has x-bound (maxX/minX) closer to the drag destination point (L2)
6. Translate L2 LineString (found in #5) to the drag destination point (affine.translate). Call it translatedL2
7. Reconstruct the polygon using coords of (L1, translatedL2)
8. Rotate back the Polygon from #7 (affine.rotate)
   [image]

[EDIT] Another example:

[image]

Comment: Interesting, thanks. If I get into problems with my solution, I'll investigate yours.

Comment: Would your algorithm work on this: https://imgur.com/a/VZQJOgA ?

Comment: @Nachiket Yes I think, check the edit in answer.

Comment: See https://imgur.com/05LzfHD  The 'V' on the top right should be closed up. This is because the right edge of the 'V' is dragged through all those points. I've circled it in red. Would your algorithm do close the 'V'?